# Standardisation and Central Limit Theorem

Tags: self-study, standardization, central-limit-theorem

i got a question about standardization: I have to calculate $P(\bar{X}<2,2)$ with $n = 100$ ;  $E[X_i] = E[\bar{X}] = 2$ and $V[X_i] = 4$ $(-> V[\bar{X}] = 0.04)$

I used the CLT:

$P(\frac{\bar{X}-2}{\sqrt{0.04}}\sqrt{100}  < \frac{2,2-2}{\sqrt{0.04}}\sqrt{100} )$ $= \phi (\frac{2,2-2}{\sqrt{0.04}}\sqrt{100}) = \phi(10) $

But it should be $\phi(1)$. It appears to be correct when i dont use $\sqrt{100}$ but it is part of the Theorem - where is my mistake ?

Comment: When $X$ has a variance of $v$, then $X/100$ has a variance of $v/10000,$ not $v/100$ as you suggest in the opening line.

Comment: I don’t quite get it. X_bar is defined as (1/n)*sum x_i for i=[1;100]; so the variance of x_bar should be equal to 100/10000 * Var(X_i) which is 4/100 and thus 0,04

Comment: Sorry; I misread your notation.  Have you noticed that you included a factor of $\sqrt{n}$ twice?  It appears in $1/\sqrt{0.04} = 1/\sqrt{4/100}$ as well as in $\sqrt{100}.$ You seem to have combined two correct formulas into one incorrect one :-).